# Update project to Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, guid

Hi I have a project that was created in a previous version to 3.5. I since then ran the wizard to upgrade it to 3.5. After I did this I built the project but it has an error. The error is that a Guid is trying to access the properties HasValue and Value:

```
if(theGuid.HasValue)
{
    id = theGuid.Value
}
```

The errors are 'System.Guid' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue' and no extension method 'HasValue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Guid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The error is similiar for the Value property.

Can someone please tell me what's going on? Is it a property that was taken out of the framework? If so what could I replace it with?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us where theGuid is defined/initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like "theGuid" should have been defined as:

```
Guid? theGuid;
```

And now, for some reason, it isn't using `Nullable<T>` in its definition, and is rather defined as:

```
Guid theGuid;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the case. I checked source control which contains before the conversion and it is a nullable type. After conversion it seems a lot of nullable types have become nonnullable. I don't know why this should have happened though.

Comment: @Mr Cricket: It shouldn't have really happened as part of the conversion.  That's a fairly odd conversion issue.

Answer (score 1):

Nullable types are still possible in 3.5.

Are you sure `theGuid` is a `Guid?` type and not just `Guid`?

Answer (score 1):

`HasValue` and `Value` are properties of the [Nullable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) struct.

So you code should work if `theGuid` was declared as [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx):

```
Guid? theGuid = //...
Guid id;

if (theGuid.HasValue)
{
    id = theGuid.Value;
}
```